# How to deserialize bing map json using C#?

Tags: c#, json, bing-maps

I have following json. I am trying to deserialize it. But I am not able to deserialize it. I have read so many blogs and tried a lot but didn't find rid of the problem.

Code:

```
string response = "";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
        response = client.DownloadString(bingMapsUri);
}
ResponseClass root = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ResponseClass>(response);
```

> {"authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials","brandLogoUri":"http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png","copyright":"Copyright
>   Â© 2017 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API
>   cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used,
>   reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written
>   permission from Microsoft
>   Corporation.","resourceSets":[{"estimatedTotal":5,"resources":[{"__type":"Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1","bbox":[22.9237632751465,72.4435119628906,23.1547412872314,72.7061538696289],"name":"Ahmedabad, India","point":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[23.0277690887451,72.6002426147461]},"address":{"adminDistrict":"Gujarat","adminDistrict2":"Ahmedabad","countryRegion":"India","formattedAddress":"Ahmedabad,
>   India","locality":"Ahmedabad"},"confidence":"High","entityType":"PopulatedPlace","geocodePoints":[{"type":"Point","coordinates":[23.0277690887451,72.6002426147461],"calculationMethod":"Rooftop","usageTypes":["Display"]}],"matchCodes":["Ambiguous"]},{"__type":"Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1","bbox":[21.5913391113281,71.8402862548828,23.5085697174072,72.844482421875],"name":"Ahmedabad","point":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[22.7821483612061,72.245231628418]},"address":{"adminDistrict":"Gujarat","adminDistrict2":"Ahmedabad","countryRegion":"India","formattedAddress":"Ahmedabad"},"confidence":"Low","entityType":"AdminDivision2","geocodePoints":[{"type":"Point","coordinates":[22.7821483612061,72.245231628418],"calculationMethod":"Rooftop","usageTypes":["Display"]}],"matchCodes":["Ambiguous"]},{"__type":"Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1","bbox":[23.001030303653,72.5380384738435,23.0589710696381,72.6219651882659],"name":"Ahmedabad
>   district,
>   India","point":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[23.0300006866455,72.5800018310547]},"address":{"adminDistrict":"Gujarat","countryRegion":"India","formattedAddress":"Ahmedabad
>   district, India","locality":"Ahmedabad
>   district"},"confidence":"Low","entityType":"PopulatedPlace","geocodePoints":[{"type":"Point","coordinates":[23.0300006866455,72.5800018310547],"calculationMethod":"Rooftop","usageTypes":["Display"]}],"matchCodes":["Ambiguous"]},{"__type":"Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1","bbox":[28.6824280233961,79.092212837441,28.6901534585375,79.1039541547465],"name":"Ahmedabad,
>   India","point":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[28.6862907409668,79.0980834960938]},"address":{"adminDistrict":"Uttar
>   Pradesh","adminDistrict2":"Rampur","countryRegion":"India","formattedAddress":"Ahmedabad,
>   India","locality":"Milak"},"confidence":"Low","entityType":"Neighborhood","geocodePoints":[{"type":"Point","coordinates":[28.6862907409668,79.0980834960938],"calculationMethod":"Rooftop","usageTypes":["Display"]}],"matchCodes":["Ambiguous"]},{"__type":"Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1","bbox":[26.9299580069166,80.6626650606104,26.937683442058,80.6742184843115],"name":"Ahmedabad,
>   India","point":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[26.9338207244873,80.6684417724609]},"address":{"adminDistrict":"Uttar
>   Pradesh","adminDistrict2":"Lucknow","countryRegion":"India","formattedAddress":"Ahmedabad,
>   India","locality":"Malihabad"},"confidence":"Low","entityType":"Neighborhood","geocodePoints":[{"type":"Point","coordinates":[26.9338207244873,80.6684417724609],"calculationMethod":"Rooftop","usageTypes":["Display"]}],"matchCodes":["Ambiguous"]}]}],"statusCode":200,"statusDescription":"OK","traceId":"e9626e57d63748bd9a2de025bd99d8e6|HK20290228|7.7.0.0|"}

Class:

```
public class ResponseClass
{
    public string copyright { get; set; }
    public string brandLogoUri { get; set; }
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public string statusDescription { get; set; }
    public string authenticationResultCode { get; set; }
    public List<string> errorDetails { get; set; }
    public string traceId { get; set; }
    public List<ResourceSet> resourceSets { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceSet
{
    public long estimatedTotal { get; set; }
    public List<Resource> resources { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public List<double> bbox { get; set; }
    public string __type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Point point { get; set; }
    public string entityType { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public string confidence { get; set; }
    public List<string> matchCodes { get; set; }
    public List<Point> geocodePoints { get; set; }
}

public class Point
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Latitude,Longitude
    /// </summary>
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
    //public string calculationMethod { get; set; }
    //public string[] usageTypes { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string addressLine { get; set; }
    public string adminDistrict { get; set; }
    public string adminDistrict2 { get; set; }
    public string countryRegion { get; set; }
    public string formattedAddress { get; set; }
    public string locality { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    public string neighborhood { get; set; }
    public string landmark { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Take a look at the Bing Maps .NET REST Toolkit, it does all this for you and just requires adding a nuget package to your app. Will save you lots of time and already implements all the best practices for the API. https://www.nuget.org/packages/BingMapsRESTToolkit